# How get Win32_OperatingSystem.LastBootUpTime in datetime format

Tags: c++, wmi

I have been trying to get LastBootUpTime using Win32_OperatingSystem class (WMI).

```
HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, 
        &pclsObj, &uReturn);

    if(0 == uReturn)
    {
        break;
    }

    VARIANT vtProp;

    // Get the value of the Name property
    hr = pclsObj->Get(L"LastBootUpTime", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);          
    VariantClear(&vtProp);
```

I want to write this time to CTime or COleDateTime variable. But variable vtProp has BSTR type and look like **20100302185848.499768+300**
Also any datetime property of any WMI class have BSTR type

How can I put datetime property of WMI class to CTime?

---

But how use SWbemDateTime.GetVarDate() in C++? In MSDN just scripting sample for this function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do some parsing to convert it.  The format is yyyyMMddhhmmss.ffffff+zzz (zzz is UTC offset in minutes).  The [SWbemDateTime.GetVarDate() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393691%28VS.85%29.aspx) can do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely ignore anything after the decimal point as in the format yyyymmddhhmmss..