# String to UTC date in C/Windows API

Tags: c, windows, datetime, time

I'm working in native C (not C++ - I'd like for everything to stay in C as much as possible) on the Windows API and I'm having trouble with dealing with/comparing UTC strings. Basically I'm getting a date from a WMI call, which as I understand it is a UTC number returned as a DWORD, and I'd like to take a human-readable date-time (i.e. 11:11:11 08/04/2014) and compare that to the UTC date I already have so I can programmatically say which comes before the other.

However it doesn't look like the Windows API provides a good API, and I tried to do it using sscanf_s and mktime similar to the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213326/how-to-convert-a-string-variable-containing-time-to-time-t-type-in-c). This gave me a number that seem close but wasn't quite correct. i.e. both will be today's date within a few minutes has the most significant 3-4 digits the same but nothing else is close.

Is this a timezone/local time problem? Or am I just missing something?

Comment: Just adding this as a ref: [ISO_8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Can you provide an example of the DWORD (unsigned long) that is printed? Everything I see shows strings.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2453191/539810) help?

Comment: Could you give a few testcases: a sample UTC you are getting, the User input date string and whats the expected result.