# How to get Windows boot time?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How can I get Windows boot time in C++ with some WinAPI functions? I am currently using the command "systeminfo", but I'm looking for a more proper solution.

Comment: Should just be System::Environment::TickCount, right?

Comment: "Proper" code would use WMI to retrieve info like this.  Win32_OperatingSystem class, LastBootUpTime property.  It does however have the tendency to no longer be considered "proper" when a C++ programmer discovers what it takes to write WMI queries.  Or really all that necessary :)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453191/how-get-win32-operatingsystem-lastbootuptime-in-datetime-format

Comment: Could you enlighten me what's wrong with this question, that it gets downvotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've checked at how Task Manager does it, and turns out it uses the `ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemTimeOfDayInformation, ...)` function, which receives the `SYSTEM_TIMEOFDAY_INFORMATION` structure.

```
typedef struct _SYSTEM_TIMEOFDAY_INFORMATION {
    LARGE_INTEGER BootTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER CurrentTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER TimeZoneBias;
    ULONG TimeZoneId;
    ULONG Reserved;
    ULONGLONG BootTimeBias;
    ULONGLONG SleepTimeBias;
} SYSTEM_TIMEOFDAY_INFORMATION, *PSYSTEM_TIMEOFDAY_INFORMATION;
```

[(source)](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/733b8930c1b0e7fb95b3da917fd299b0c9472a6f/psutil/arch/windows/ntextapi.h#L73-L81)

`BootTime` is what you're looking for.

For something more documented, I think `GetTickCount64` will do.

Comment: That seems pretty unlikely to be true. How would the value returned be simultaneously be used for generating an unpredictable seed for a random number generator, and for reading the system boot time?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, just Googled [this](http://read.pudn.com/downloads136/sourcecode/windows/network/578829/snmp/common/dll/uptime.c__.htm).

Comment: That is code to measure elapsed time. The question asks for the time taken for the system to boot. Which is different.

Comment: Or perhaps what is asked for is the time at which the system started. Either way, your answer does not address that.

Comment: I think it's the latter. What I'm talking about is [this](http://i.imgur.com/WwJa7C3.png).

Comment: As I said, either way, your answer doesn't address the question.

Comment: Why not? It provides you with the system boot time. Updated answer with more information. Task manager calculates the Up Time by doing `CurrentTime-BootTime`.

Comment: OK, that's more like it. Now you've given some more useful information. However, this is undocumented. We've no real idea whether or not the struct really contains those members. In all versions of windows. Even future ones. So, I certainly would not attempt to abuse this function for something that it was not intended for.

Comment: It depends on what the OP needs. Also, see the latest line of my answer.

Comment: How does `GetTickCount64` handle system sleep states?

Comment: "The elapsed time retrieved by `GetTickCount` or `GetTickCount64` includes time the system spends in sleep or hibernation." [(source)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725496.aspx)

Comment: See a blog post on [The Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2015/05/12/10614015.aspx)

Comment: Note that `ZwQuerySystemInformation` [is no longer available for use as of Windows 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725506(v=vs.85).aspx); moreover, the suggested alternative on MSDN for `SystemTimeOfDayInformation` is `CryptGenRandom`... which does not help in getting the boot time.

Comment: @Andy it's still available on my Windows 10. What they meant is probably that it's no longer supported.

Comment: @Paul SystemTimeOfDayInformation returns random garbage: "Returns an opaque SYSTEM_TIMEOFDAY_INFORMATION structure that can be used to generate an unpredictable seed for a random number generator. Use the CryptGenRandom function instead".

Comment: @Alex the fact that it can be used as a seed doesn't mean it's random garbage. In C, you use `srand(time(NULL))`, but `time(NULL)` doesn't return garbage. And in any case, that's the call Task Manager uses for displaying the boot time information. So it must be working, unless you see random garbage in your Task Manager.

Comment: @Paul Well, I though it was changed in some version of Windows, since it was undocumented (Task Manager could be rewritten as well). However, now I've checked that it still returns boot time.